# Access rules in CQRS read model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, cqrs

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET MVC3 which uses CQRS pattern. The command side is made with Entity Framework, entities are mapped to tables in SQL Server. The query side is built on top of SQL views (also uses EF).

How should I manage the access to data? For example there is a Document. The Document could be protected with a password and accessible to any one who knows it or it could be accessible only for a given logged in users.

Where and how the logic of allowing/denying access should be implemented? What data should be included in the DocumentViewModel? Should it contain a password field to compare it with password provided by the user, so I could check access and get data for display in a single query? Or should it contain just fields that will be displayed in UI, thus a separate query (or stored procedure call?) will be responsible for checking access?

What if access rules are more sophisticated than just checking password - that might include all white lists, black lists, payments, transfer limits, account type, etc? 
In general - things very far from

```
SELECT * FROM ReadModelTable WHERE id = @id
```

that is often showed in examples of 'good' read scenarios.

Comment: A user should **authenticate** once, for which you can choose several strategies, but that would usually involve username/password. After that, you're dealing with **authorization**. It always helps to separate these two responsibilities. However, your question is to vague to see where to start helping. The specifications seem to be a moving target and it is not clear what you've got so far (and whether you need basic or more advanced support).

Comment: Currently the specifications requires 2 strategies of protecting access to the document (authorization): with a generic password related to the document itself or with user access list. Or both. Authentication is implemented with MembershipProviders and is outside of scope of the domain model.

Comment: Well, I don't want the answer related to this particular example but rather a generic pattern to deal with complex (and likely to change) authorization scenarios in CQRS.

Answer (score 1):

[Episode 28 of Being the Worst (Podcast)](http://beingtheworst.com/2013/episode-28-learning-lokad-cqrs) has some interesting points on authorization and authentication for systems that use CQRS. I've often considered authentication after listening to others and coming up with theoretical system architectures as a concern normally outside of the core domain. Authorization on the other hand could have elements within the core domain but also seem to be somewhat cross cutting concerns in many systems.

In your example, if dealing with some type of document aggregate where each needs to have a separate user name and password then what your proposing would work but it doesn't sound like a typical implementation. The main failing point is that the credentials reside with the document and are presumably shared between users which is a security concern and makes revoking a single user's access rights in the future problematic. Think like a secrete club where each member needs to know the secrete password. If the password never changes then you have a problem when somebody gets kicked out of the club or accidentally shares the password with an unintended party.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the issue with that - that's why it's just a one of the alternatives. This shared password strategy is intended for a scenario when the users want to quickly create an ad-hoc workgroup to review a proposed design/project/document. Nothing long-lasting.

Comment: In this case the ad-hoc workgroup password sounds like a business concern that is involved in the domain itself. Only note that I have other than this is that of course it would make sense to use a password hash in the storage and comparison of the password for better security. As far as where to put the access domain logic, sounds like the password itself could to be part of any command or query related to that document entity and logic could be placed in the corresponding handler.